# React JS Front-end & Node js Server deployment on shared hosting

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working on react js project & using node js for backend(to handle DB as well as to run CRON JOBs). At my local machine I had created 2 folders "botclient" & 'botserver". I starts the server using "node server.js" in 1 command prompt & in another command prompt, I satrs client  using "npm start". Now in browser I use "http://localhost:3000 & my application works.
Now my client has given me 1 shared hosted domain something like **http://mybot.hismaindomain.in.**
Now he has given me cPanel credentials to deploy this app. I have no idea how should I deploy it on server. I had tried lots of threads like "running nodejs react in one directory" or "react js nodejs deployment on hosted server" But I could not deploy the application on Hosted server.
I am total newbie in this technology so please help me to solve this problem. Whether I am doing wrong folder structure? Whether I need 2 sub domains?(for client and server separately)
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you are creating a web server ? Using Express  ?

Comment: Yes. Using Express

Comment: So this can be done something like ,  run `build` command to bundle, minify and optimize all front end code into HTML, CSS and JavaScript files in the build folder. The entire React application will serve through the entry point botclient/build/index.html. Import  and add to `Server`  `this.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,“../botclient/build”)));`

Comment: If you are using Heroku then create a new app , install CLI push from github   and make sure Node's   `package.json` ( the one with express) file is at the root of directory structure .

Answer (score 0):

(This should be a comment but I csan't comment yet)
Maybe try using cPanel cron job to run the *node* command

Answer (score 0):

You do not need two sub-domains. Neither do you need a specific folder structure to have shared hosting.

To run node two or more servers on the same host, from the same repository, from just one command line, you can use a package like 'concurrently' or 'npm-run-all', which lets one `npm start`-command activate a number of processes in parallell. For example: `concurrently \"node server.js --port 4000\" \"webpack --config client/webpack.config.js --port 3000\" \"node cron-jobs.js\"`. In this example, the server is in the project root, and the react app is in client subfolder with its own package.json.

Then, to share a domain it is necessary to setup a reverse proxy, so that the backend's port can be accessed via a designated path, ie: `/api`. There are many ways to do it and there are others who would explain it better than me. Try google `react node config reverse proxy` or similar. Good to know is that the easiest solutions might be limited to a dev server, while the more complicated ones (like nginx) are independent on your tech stack (which you might not need).

For cron jobs, you could try a package like 'node-cron', [check this guide for the basics](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/schedule-a-job-in-node-with-nodecron/)

Comment: I googled "react node config reverse proxy" and found some useful resource. I had updated client's package.json with "proxy": ""http://localhost:3001"  but still its not available. Do I need to open the Port 3001?

Comment: Do you use create-react-app? The config you mentioned in package.json would not have an effect otherwise.

No need to open ports publicly. The idea is to only expose one port, for which certain requests will be redirected internally to another port.

Comment: Yes I used **"create-react-app"**. I had create server app using **"express generator"** & in terminal I am starting server using **PORT=3001 node bin/www** I had published Server using Application Manager in cPanel.

Client is in public_html\myapp folder and calling this from any browser as http://myapp.mydomain.in
**I have removed "proxy: http://localhost:3001" from client's package.json** because it wont hit to my server. So I am calling server as follows
axios.get('http://server.mydomain.in:3001/getUsers').then(...)
Currently it's working but I need to know is it good approach?

Comment: That's great you could unblock yourself. It may be good enough given your situation. There may be problems later on, for example if you need the site to use https and use cookies. In that case, I'd recommend to try to fix the reverse proxy using the tools available in cPanel Application manager. Looking at the documentation, it seems that "Phusion passenger" has a reverse proxy feature.